# I want to find a value from one cell, and if found print the contents of another cell in the same Row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Let's say Cell L:23 contains a certain value I search for. If the Value is found, I want it to print the Contents of a Cell Horizontal to it, say D:23, in a Cell I Choose.

How could this be accomplished?

Comment: You can try `INDEX/MATCH`, `FILTER`, `Query()` may also work.

Answer (score 0):

In cell **D23**, I would use the formula: `=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("search_value", L23)),"Not Found",L23)`
In short, this means that if the substring "search_value" is found in cell L23, print the content in **L23**; else print "Not Found".
In its entirety, it's saying if the `SEARCH()` query had found a match and doesn't return an error, the `ISERROR()` function it's wrapped in will return false, therefore it will print **L23**.